# Unity Launcher missing and Terminal shortcut stopped working

Tags: 12.04, unity, gnome-terminal

When I restarted my Ubuntu after it being updated, I found the Unity launch bar was gone.

I tried looking up several solutions online, blindly typing in the commands that others suggested, and I found after the umpteenth time rebooting after typing in another foreign command, I found I couldn't even open up the terminal with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> shortcut either and I have no idea how to fix this.

This was the last set of instructions I remember following before terminal stopped opening.

Install CCSM

`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

And then run it in terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>)

`ccsm`

Then search for "Ubuntu Unity Plugin". If it's not checked, check it.

If it is checked you may have another issue. Try restarting compiz:

`kill -9`pidof compiz`

This will kill it, it should start up again, if it doesn't, CTRL+ALT+F2 and then type:

`sudo service lightdm restart`

to restart the window manager. Go back to the terminal and run:

`unity --reset`

Answer (score 2):

I just had exactly the same problem on Ubuntu 13.10. Unity launcher gone and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> shortcut not working. I opened xterm by typing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and tried `unity --reset`, but that did not work since it is deprecated in ubuntu > 12.10.

This solution worked for me:

1. Log into unity.
2. Right click on the desktop and create a new folder.
3. Open the folder and go to */usr/bin* and start gnome-terminal by clicking on it.
4. Type `ccsm` in the terminal to start compiz config settings manager.
5. Go to preferences -> plugin list.
6. Uncheck the automatic plugin list. And enable all the plugins.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on desktop and create new folder
2. open folder and go to /usr/bin and double click on gnome-terminal
3. type in `sudo open unity` and type in password

That shall be it

Comment: It may be better/easier to run that command from outside of the current desktop session. You can change to an actual terminal with Ctrl+Alt+F1.